# Error java.io.FileNotFound BufferReader with InputStreamReader Java Android

Tags: java, android

I want the get some data from my database on my android application. This is my code:

```
try{
            String nome = (String)arg0[0];
            String stato = (String)arg0[1];
            String link="http://www.example.org/AndroidPage.php";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("nome", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nome, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("stato", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(stato, "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();



           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
         }catch(Exception e){
            return new String("exception: " + e.toString());
        }
```

If I comment the BufferReader statement I don't get any error. Here is the error..
(The file exist in the server)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb3sc.png

UPDATE:
I resolved the problem.. The error was inside the php script, I forgot to write a semicolon.

Comment: try using   new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

Comment: I can use it but it doesn't have the method "reader.readLine()"

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Internet permission to the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```